# Why does my xsd validates an undeclared attribute?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an xml I want to validate against an xsd after adding a new attribute. 
I tried to declare the attribute locally for some element in the xsd, but couldn't figure out how to do it.
On a whim, I took an already validated xml and added the new attribute to an element without any change to the xsd, and the validation passed successfully.

The attribute (letter-spacing) passed the validation only of it had a namespace prefix (namespace 'dptt' that is defined in the xsd and appears in the xml):
An example of a line that passed the validation:

```
<tt:style dptt:letter-spacing="4px" style="s01" tts:lineHeight="120px" xml:id="1"/>
```

An example of a line that didn't pass the validation:

```
<tt:style letter-spacing="4px" style="s01" tts:lineHeight="120px" xml:id="1"/>
```

This is the part of the xsd that defines the style attribute:

```
<xs:element name="style">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="tt:metadata" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="xml:id" use="required">
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="style" type="xs:IDREFS">
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute ref="tts:direction" >
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute ref="tts:fontFamily" >
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute ref="tts:fontSize" >
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute ref="tts:lineHeight" >
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute ref="tts:textAlign" >
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute ref="tts:color" >
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute ref="tts:backgroundColor" >
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute ref="tts:fontStyle" >
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute ref="tts:fontWeight" >
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute ref="tts:textDecoration" >
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute ref="tts:unicodeBidi" >
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute ref="tts:padding">
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute ref="ebutts:multiRowAlign"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I expect that an undeclared attribute won't pass the validation.
I also wonder why the addition of a namespace is crucial for validation.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the schema we can't possibly know. My guess would be that the complex type of the containing element included an `xs:anyAttribute` wildcard.

Comment: There is no xs:anyAttribute wildcard in the definition of the style attribute. I updated the question.

Comment: Is it perhaps an XSD 1.1 schema with an open content model? Sorry, I'm still having to make guesses about what might be in the part of the schema you haven't shown us. Suggest you construct a repro in which we have complete information.

Comment: It was indeed some element that included an ```xs:anyAttribute``` wildcard. It was hidden in some xsd that I've found after 5-6 references while jumping from one xsd to another. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the schema referenced a different element than the one I thought it was referencing.
Took me a while to notice that the element from the xml

```
<tt:style letter-spacing="4px" style="s01" tts:lineHeight="120px" xml:id="1"/>
```

is not the same element from the xsd

```
<xs:element name="style">...</xs:element>
```

The tt:style element is defined somewhere else, and indeed contains a `<xs:anyAttribute>` element in one of the many referenced xsd.